# Remote interpreter and local plot in PyCharm?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ssh, pycharm, xserver

I'm using PyCharm with a remote interpreter. My code is `show`ing a `scatter` `figure` using `matplotlib`. I can see the figure normally and interact with (zoom and rotate), but the interaction is too slow. I think this is because it's done through the SSH X-server.

My question is how to manually make the figure interactions graphically (using mouse, like zooming, panning, rotation, ...) execute faster? I think this should be via allowing the figure interactions to happen on local machine (machine running PyCharm), not the remote server.

One workaround is to save a `.fig` file, then copy it to my local machine, then load it. But I don't prefer this workaround.

Comment: I think the idea doesn't take into account that the code that performs the interactions necessarily needs to run on the server.

Comment: Why do you need to run the visualisation on a remote server? Is it because data generation is too slow or because the amount of data is large or something else?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I mean interacting with the figure using the mouse graphically, there is no code that do the interaction. Sorry my question was not clear, I have edited it to mention this explicitly.

Comment: @ThomasKühn The data I'm trying to visualize is in the remote server (because of its big size). I visualize individual files which are small. So another workaround would be to use the local interpreter, and write a script the copies only the needed file then visualize it. But I don't prefer this workaround.

Comment: The code that is responsible for "interacting with the figure using the mouse graphically" is [in the backends](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/tree/master/lib/matplotlib/backends), i.e. it necessarily is part of the code run on the server.

Comment: My thought here was that one could maybe mount the data directory of the remote server as a local folder using something like `sshfs` and then run the script locally. Depending on the size of the data file you process, this would most likely slow down the figure generation, but make the figure more responsive. With a little bit of planning, one could write a script that first generates pre-processed data and saves it, so that the process does not need to be repeated. It all depends on what you are trying to do...

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for the information. I wrongly assumed it's part of PyCharm.

Comment: @ThomasKühn Thanks, it's a good workaround that is similar to he one I mentioned. But the question remains open, can we make figure GUI interactions faster while using a remote interpreter?

Comment: Is this for data science?

Comment: Well, the main problem is that if you run your script on a remote server, the response times of the GUI are limited by your data connection. So if you really want to do things this way I'm guessing that the only answer is to improve connection speed, which has nothing to do with matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

Interacting with visualisations on separate windows is slow, not just on PyCharm but any IDE that you specify visualisations to be loaded separately. This is because they are loaded on either `tkinter` or any of the available modules like `Qt5` and if you're on a mac, you can also use the inbuilt OSX rendering. Especially if your dataset is large then interaction becomes slower. It just seems that visualisations in Python are not exactly that optimised as you witness on Tableau or even Orange/Glue.

That's why I personally prefer visualising data inline through the IPython console (for that I use Spyder). You cannot interact with plots though, but the purpose suffices.